# How to upgrade my samsung galaxy ace plus GT -S7500 from Gingerbread to Jellybean

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace-plus

I would like to know How to upgrade my samsung galaxy ace plus GT-S7500 from Gingerbread to Jellybean.?

Details are as follows

1. Model Number: Samsung GT-S7500
2. Android version: 2.3.6
3. Baseband Version: S7500DDME1
4. Kernel Version: 2.6.38.6
                  dpi@DELL235#1
5. Build Number: GINGERBREAD.DDMF2

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your phone might be a bit tricky, because you can brick it and leave it unusable.
I will advice you to read some tutorials [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2209156).
There you will find information regarding different roms, and also the process to update them. I will advice to read carefully before starting.